# ReferenceError: google is not defined, only (mozilla)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I trying to use google maps API with custom marks, on chrome work fine, but other browsers i have errors.

First error:

```
ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

Second error:

```
InvalidValueError: mapInitialize is not a function
```

JSfiddle example: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/g84o8v02/3/)

on test site: [testsite](http://dev.animalslife.net/ru/google-map/)

What i do wrong? Please help!

Comment: Define `mapInitialize()` outside of `$(function(){` on test site

Comment: Now i have only => google is not defined

Comment: I checked again and saw this error `document.getElementsByTagName(...)[0] is undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add this code at end of `mapInitialize` function** :

```
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(56.946528, 24.118665);
map.setCenter(mapCenter);
```

[image: Image result]

Comment: now i have next error : Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined, if i delete function log, i have google is not defined (( what i do wrong?

Comment: See my update please, You have to define this code `var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(56.946528, 24.118665); map.setCenter(mapCenter);` inner `mapInitialize` function, not outer

Answer (score 1):

You're not initialising your map correctly:

```js
function loadScript(src, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    if(callback)script.onload=callback;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    script.src = src;
}

loadScript('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=initialize',
    function() {
        log('google-loader has been loaded, but not the maps-API ');
    });

function initialize() {
    log('maps-API has been loaded, ready to use');
    var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
}

function log(str) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode('['+new Date().getTime()+']\n'+str+'\n\n'));
}
```

```html
<pre><div id="map_canvas" style="height:200px"></div><pre>
```

Comment: I did by your template, the same error, google is not defined, and google chrome have the same error, (jsfiddle example update)

Answer (score -1):

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>`

Guessing you don't have the JavaScript loaded.

Comment: And why is this happening?

Comment: If you don't have the JavaScript file loaded it won't know what 'google' is. If the script is loaded. Disable all firefox plugins and try to reload the page, some firefox plugins for some reason tamper with the google maps API.